# How does time pass?

Tags: neptunia-v

When I go into dungeons, days pass and my Scouts finish their work. It seems to pass quite quickly, as popping into a dungeon and defeating a single enemy is enough for scouts to return from a relatively brief mission.

But how does time pass exactly? Does a number of minutes inside a dungeon count as a number of days for Scouts, or is it how many enemies you defeat, what dungeon you go into or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that affects the number of days that pass in a dungeon is the **Scouting Time** of a dungeon, which you can check with L1/R1 on the map. Each dungeon has a time from 1-12 representing how many days it takes to go through it. This number ain't just for scouts, it's for you too! And it doesn't matter what you do in the dungeon - immediately entering and then exiting a 10 day dungeon will make 10 days pass, while idling for 48 hours in a 1 day dungeon to collect challenge data will still only make 1 day pass. You have to actually leave the dungeon for time to pass. Coincidentally, this means that you can send a scout to a dungeon and choose that exact dungeon to finish their journey.

A scout's resting period is always 3 days from report time, regardless of how long of a journey they went, and how many extra days passed between when they finished and when you read the actual report. So for example, if your objective is to cycle scouts frequently, then you should be frequently going through 3+ day dungeons. If you wanted to cycle in longer dungeons (y'know, to actually scout and harvest at them), then you can just enter and exit them big dungeons. Don't forget to set auto-dispatch for this if you want the convenience, I hope you've been printing enough credits to support all of the scouting.

Aside from scout timing, time passage also affects how long report effects like drop rate, Gather Shift, and Risky/Tough foes last. With proper assignment, you can send scouts to multiple destinations for simultaneous reports, and if the report effects last long enough (their duration is on the same page as the dungeon's Scouting Time), then you could visit multiple dungeons in a row to reap as many effects.